# Output loop Ggplot2 figures to pdf: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can somebody help me solve this error? After a lot of googling and frustration I can't find a solution. Plotting the data without output to pdf works fine. Essentially I just want all the plots to go to one pdf.

```
model <- y~x
plot_list = list()
for(i in 4:ncol(test)) {
  print(ggplot(test, aes(x= time, y= test[ , i])) +
          geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
          ggtitle(colnames(test)[i])+
          facet_wrap(~Group, scales = "free_y") +
          geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = model, se = F) +
          stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), 
                       label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15,
                       formula = model, parse = TRUE, size = 3)+
          stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm',
                          method.args = list(formula = model),
                          geom = 'text',
                          aes(label = paste("P-value = ", signif(..p.value.., digits = 4), sep = "")),
                          label.x = 'right', label.y = 0.35, size = 3))
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

pdf("plots.pdf")
for (i in 4:ncol(test)) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

**error: Error in plot_list[[i]] : subscript out of bounds**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `p` in the first `for` loop so `plot_list[[i]] = p` doesn't work. If you assign output of `ggplot` to `p` it should work.

Alternatively you don't need to save the output to a list and then write a separate loop to print them, you can do this in the same `for` loop.

You can do something like this that does not require to create `plot_list` at all.

```
model <- y~x
pdf("plots.pdf")

for(i in 4:ncol(test)) {
  print(ggplot(test, aes(x= time, y= test[ , i])) +
          geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
          ggtitle(colnames(test)[i])+
          facet_wrap(~Group, scales = "free_y") +
          geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = model, se = F) +
          stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), 
                       label.x.npc = "right", label.y.npc = 0.15,
                       formula = model, parse = TRUE, size = 3)+
          stat_fit_glance(method = 'lm',
                          method.args = list(formula = model),
                          geom = 'text',
                          aes(label = paste("P-value = ", signif(..p.value.., digits = 4), sep = "")),
                          label.x = 'right', label.y = 0.35, size = 3))
}
dev.off()
```